# Webscraping table from CNES

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape this [table](http://cnes.datasus.gov.br/pages/estabelecimentos/consulta.jsp?search=2259982) using rvest but I'm not succeeding at it. The problem seems to be finding the right xpath or css selector for it but I'm not really sure. Does anyone have any tips on how to get this table into R? Thanks in advance!

The code I'm currently using is this:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
url <- "http://cnes.datasus.gov.br/pages/estabelecimentos/consulta.jsp?search=2259982"
page<-read_html(url)
page%>% html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/table") %>% html_text()
```

Comment: the url is not valid

Comment: Sorry @Floo0, I don't know what you mean. Could you be more specific, please? If I copy and paste this url, my browser will open up the page I'm interested on scraping. Besides that, the read_html function does not return an error. Wouldn't it be the case if the url was not valid? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: try to open the URL from a incognito session a different browser... I do receive 404 when opening it...

Comment: It still seems to work fine here. I've tried it with Chrome and Firefox. Could this issue with the url be related to the country in which these informations are hosted? The data are from the Brazilian National Register of Health Centers.

Comment: That might me... From austria it is not accessible.

Comment: Also 404'd  in the US...